# Changing the Vim backward search key from semicolon to period

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to change the key used for going backwards in search results while using Vim.

Currently, the key used is the semicolon (`,`), but this conflicts with another function in my config.

I would like to change the key to a period (`.`) instead.

How can I make this change?

Comment: 1. "Semicolon" or "colon"? 2. What do you call "backward search" exactly? 3. Do you really want to lose `:help .`?

Comment: `,` is a comma.

Comment: @romainl when i enter search, and enter pattern, and it highlights matching patterns. I can move to next occurence with ; and previous occurence with ,

Comment: Well, that's not at all what `:help ,` and `:help ;` are supposed to do. Next match is supposed to b `:help n` and previous match is supposed to be `:help N`. So it looks like you have some custom mappings somewhere. Find them, remove them, and you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome vi.SE @igor-lerinc
It's like you are looking for remapping. Something like:

```
nnoremap . ,
```

Use the command alone to list all mapping and plugins that provide them:

```
:nmap
```

For more usage, read `:help :map` and `:help :nore`

Update based on comments.
First open your `~/.vimrc` and search for previous mapping

```
/\mmap\s+,\s+N
```

Replace that line with this new one

```
nnoremap . N
```

Save and exit. Now within your Vim sessions you'll be able to repeat your search backward with dot.

Comment: when i enter search, and enter pattern, and it highlights matching patterns. I can move to next occurence with ; and previous occurence with ,                                                               so i want, to remap colon (,) to dot (.) i this case

Comment: Oh… you mean search with `/`pattern or `?`pattern do you? Normal mapping is `n` and `N` ...you where looking for `nnoremap . N` :)